# How to Hide Sql Server Fingerprint?

Tags: sql-server, security

I have a sql server which being monitor by Nagios through snmp string.
One day, i received some alert from nagios come with some sensitive information like:

```
Critical Alert: dbi connect (Server name: ABC, Encrypted Password: 1, User: 
Sa.......)
```

How can i hide this ?

Comment: If Nagios can be configured such that it doesn't send the error message, that may be your only real option.  I can remember this being an issue at an old employer that used Nagios as the primary alerting tool, but I can't remember how we handled it. 
 Hopefully, someone with more current experience can provide you with a formal answer though.

Comment: Thanks you, will deal with nagios

Answer (score 0):

Why would you *want* to?

> Critical Alert: ... User: >>> sa <<< ...

This could indicate a script or application attempting to connect to a database using "sa" credentials, which should **never** be allowed.

> Critical Alert: ... >>> Encrypted Password: 1 <<<, User: sa ...

This could actually indicate someone trying to *hack* your "sa" account.

Both of these require your attention.

Comment: Plenty of information that can be considered sensitive hits the `ERRORLOG`s.  The most common that comes to mind is a unique key constraint error that will throw the data generating the error.  This data could be sensitive and much to the OPs's point, should probably be obfuscated from a third party alert that may cross clear-text mediums.

Comment: Not being hack, just a alert from Nagios with snmp string which allow monitor when the connection error